# Редактирование файлов одновременно с другом

Tags: javascript, java, c#, python, c

Встал вопрос о том, что нужно реализовать синхронную разработку.

Грубо говоря, файл лежит в папке на диске.

Запускаем текстовые редакторы на двух компьютерах и сделать так, чтобы я, к примеру, вносил какие-то изменение в редакторе и они моментально прилетали моему другу.

С его стороны тож самое.

P.S Расположение файла изменять нельзя

Comment: тот-же вопрос интересовал нас с другом некоторое время назад, думали сделать через базу данных, но выбрали решение попроще мы разделили программу на множество частей и каждый занимался своей частью

Comment: [JupyterLab+Real Time Collaboration (video)](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/PyData/Seattle2017/BRK11). Чтобы [попробовать online, не устанавливая](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-demo/master?urlpath=lab%2Ftree%2Fdemo)

Comment: хороший обзор в тему: [Data Laced with History: Causal Trees & Operational CRDTs](http://archagon.net/blog/2018/03/24/data-laced-with-history/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для реализации совместного редактирования исходников в реальном времени существует большое количество плагинов для популярных текстовых редакторов и IDE. Например, это [togetherly](https://github.com/zk-phi/togetherly) для Emacs, либо [CoVim](https://github.com/FredKSchott/CoVim) для vim. А можно посмотреть и в сторону онлайн-сервисов, обеспечивающих подобный функционал: тут всё зависит от используемых вами технологий.

Вот, например, скринкаст с togetherly, на котором видно, что это, и как оно вообще работает:

[image: screencast]

На мой взгляд, подобные тулзы очень удобны, когда необходимо удалённо обсудить работу конкретной части проекта, задать вопросы, etc. Но пользоваться таким режимом для совместной разработки - это вряд ли, скорее, Вам с другом стоит организовать работу, используя какую-либо VCS.

Comment: За 20+ лет в разработке, в том числе удалённо, ни разу не встречал случая, когда это было бы удобно.

Comment: @PinkTux: для объяснений удобно (общие tmux сессии, e.g, чтобы показать работу в командной строке)¶ Когда совместно, что-то в реальном времени делается, то для опоры простой текстовый документ (etherpad), который статус текущий поддерживает и чат можно использовать (e.g., для отладки сисадминских инструкций)¶ В простом коде ошибку объяснить и поправить (pythontutor.com). В общем для синхронного взаимодействия (телефон/skype vs. асинхронное: e-mail/git )

Answer (score 6):

Одновременную разработку ведут в системах версионного контроля (git, mercurial, tfs - все современные системы cvs являются dcvs, то есть распределёнными)

Если же вы хотите сделать собственную систему, в которой одновременно с разных мест редактировать файл.

Это очень непростой вопрос, в котором множество мелочей.

Почитайте вот такие две статьи:

- [Совместное редактирование. Часть 1](https://habrahabr.ru/company/ncloudtech/blog/264923/)
- [Совместное редактирование. Часть 2](https://habrahabr.ru/company/ncloudtech/blog/266429/)

Возможные подходы

- Блокировка всего документа при редактировании
- Блокировка части документа
- Differential synchronization
- Operation Transformation

Наиболее подходящим в вашем конкретном случае мне кажется последний вариант.

> В основе OT лежит довольно простая идея. Все изменения данных мы
>   описываем как операции, которые пересылаем и преобразуем относительно
>   других без самого документа. Когда операция приходит от одного
>   пользователя к другому, мы ее трансформируем таким образом, чтобы она
>   стала валидной относительно разницы между документами этих двух
>   пользователей, выраженной в операциях. Звучит заумно, но на самом деле
>   принцип довольно простой.

Comment: интересные статьи - спасибо

Comment: JupyterLab среда упомянутая выше является примером где совместное редактирование с помощью operational transformation операций (сейчас поверх Google Drive работает).

Comment: @jfs почему не оформили ответом?

Comment: Стандартные эппловские Notes умеют, кстати, неплохо.