# Есть ли IDE для C# для совместной разработки?

Tags: c#

Есть ли какие-нибудь компиляторы кода C# с поддержкой

> "совместного создания кода в режиме реального времени. Можно
>   подключить коллег к общей среде разработки за несколько щелчков мышью
>   и работать над кодом вместе. Во время совместной работы все участники
>   могут в режиме реального времени видеть код, создаваемый другими, и
>   общаться в чате прямо в IDE."

Comment: Во-первых, компилятор и IDE - это разные вещи. Во-вторых, какое отношение к вопросу имеют теги python, java и javascript?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Редактирование файлов одновременно с другом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/790064/23044)

Comment: Если то, что вы собираетесь писать, будет состоять больше, чем из пары файлов, то неплохо было бы использовать систему контроля версий вроде git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, Visual Studio. Для нее есть расширение Visual Studio Live Share для совместного просмотра и редактирования кода. Плюс TFS или git или ещё что-нибудь по вкусу, для контроля версий кода.