# Одновременное чтение и запись в файл

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, filestream

Пишу клиент-сервер, где один клиент пишет в файл, а другие клиенты просматривают изменения. Хочу достичь чего-то вроде Google Document. 
Суть проблемы в следующем - есть файл который всегда открыт на запись. Нужно прочитать из этого файла, но при попытке чтения из этого файла вылетает исключение: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Tpoc3\source\repos\Bachelor-s-Project\TextEditorServer\bin\Debug\files\111Storage.txt' because it is being used by another process.'

Понятное дело, что файл занят другим процессом, но как обеспечить одновременный доступ к нему?

Comment: Клиенты лезут к файлу все через один сервер?

Comment: это так не делается. обычно это делается через базу, либо специальными алгоритмами. Посмотрите тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/790064/213987

Comment: `mmap(..)` или любая технология `Shared segment`

Comment: Укажите правильное сочетание флагов [FileMode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode?view=netframework-4.8), [FileShare](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileshare?view=netframework-4.8), [FileAccess](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileaccess?view=netframework-4.8). И вот: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/670623/184217

Comment: А чем кстати `Google Document` не устроил? То что вы хотите, называется `система управления версиями` по своей сути. Если вы немного задумайтесь как обеспечивать просмотр изменений на клиентах, то станет очевидным необходимость дифф срезов и их индексов.. и это только начало..

Comment: @Vasek, да. Предполагается, что к одному файлу будет один поток на запись  и от 0 до 5 потоков на чтение.